# KeyboardDismissMode crashes the app

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield

So, I have my UItableView, and I fetch the data from the web to some array and show it in the tableView. Also, I have a UITextField that is acting basically like a search bar for this tableView. You type a text in this text field, click Search and the tableView table gets generated.

And here is the problem: I tried to implement the new exciting feature presented in iOS 7 - keyboardDimissMode to hide the keyboard when scrolling starts, but it works OK only if I have dozens of cells (basically, if I have more than one screen). If I have no results, or just 2-3 results and I have my keyboard on the screen, and then I start scroll the screen down - app crashes with sigabrt error right away.

It doesn't matter if I use a checkbox in my storyboard or type something like

```
self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```

it crashes anyway.

If I do it the old style, like this

```
    - (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

then it works just fine.
And when this happens it doesn't even go to cellForRowAtIndexPath or anything like that, just crashes right away.

And there is more: I tried to also implement UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive mode - and the keyboard doesn't get dismissed on touch at all for me.

But if I do it, again, old style - works without any problems. Like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

So, my question is: is this feature really buggy for now, or I'm doing something wrong here?
Thank you.

Comment: What does the crash log in the debugger say?

Comment: That's the stack trace. I'm looking for what it says in the console (If anything).

Comment: Ah, then no. It says just nothing, that's the hard part. It doesn't give me any reason why it happens. Just crashes.